# How to pass a form object in a request object in Django unit test?

Tags: django

Suppose I have an unit test which tests a view. That view requires a form to do some processing. My unit test looks like this:

```
class ViewTests(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.factory = RequestFactory()

def test_login_view_post(self):
    # require form object to pass it in post function
    response = self.client.post(reverse('login'))
    self.assertContains(response, "Your username and password didn't match", status_code=200)
```

Can someone tell me that how can I pass the form object in the post function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually pass the form object in the post, you pass the form data as if the form was being submitted (which is what you are simulating)

```
post_data = {
    "username": "foo",
    "password": "bar"
}
response = self.client.post(reverse('login'), data=post_data)
```

Or you can simply include the form in another test and instantiate it with data to test its validity.

```
def test_form(self):
    data = {
        "username": "foo",
        "password": "bar"
    }
    form = LoginForm(data)
    self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```